# Minecraft Skin Viewer PHP form

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap, minecraft

I have a little question.
I have downloaded this file, where the PHP script for finding a skin is possible. It works perfectly. The problem is that I want to make a form.

I'm making a textbox, but I don't know what to "name" it.
The PHP code is like this:

```
<?php

/*
Title:      Minecraft Avatar
URL:        http://github.com/jamiebicknell/Minecraft-Avatar
Author:     Jamie Bicknell
Twitter:    @jamiebicknell
*/

$size = isset($_GET['s']) ? max(40,min(2000,$_GET['s'])) : 250;
$user = isset($_GET['u']) ? $_GET['u'] : 'char';

function get_skin($user = 'char') {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://s3.amazonaws.com/MinecraftSkins/' . $user . '.png');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    $status = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    curl_close($ch);
    if($status!='200') {
        // Default Skin: http://www.minecraft.net/skin/char.png
        $output = 'iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAEAAAAAgCAMAAACVQ462AAAABGdBTUEAALGPC/xhBQAAAwBQTFRFAAAAHxALIxcJJBgIJBgKJhgLJhoKJx';
        $output .= 'sLJhoMKBsKKBsLKBoNKBwLKRwMKh0NKx4NKx4OLR0OLB4OLx8PLB4RLyANLSAQLyIRMiMQMyQRNCUSOigUPyoVKCgoPz8/JiFbMChyAFt';
        $output .= 'bAGBgAGhoAH9/Qh0KQSEMRSIOQioSUigmUTElYkMvbUMqb0UsakAwdUcvdEgvek4za2trOjGJUj2JRjqlVknMAJmZAJ6eAKioAK+vAMzM';
        $output .= 'ikw9gFM0hFIxhlM0gVM5g1U7h1U7h1g6ilk7iFo5j14+kF5Dll9All9BmmNEnGNFnGNGmmRKnGdIn2hJnGlMnWpPlm9bnHJcompHrHZaq';
        $output .= 'n1ms3titXtnrYBttIRttolsvohst4Jyu4lyvYtyvY5yvY50xpaA////AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA';
        $output .= 'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA';
        $output .= 'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA';
        $output .= 'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA';
        $output .= 'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA';
        $output .= 'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA';
        $output .= 'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAPSUN6AAAAQB0Uk5T////////////////////////////////////////';
        $output .= '/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////';
        $output .= '/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////';
        $output .= '//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////AFP3ByUAAAAYdEV';
        $output .= 'YdFNvZnR3YXJlAFBhaW50Lk5FVCB2My4zNqnn4iUAAAKjSURBVEhLpZSLVtNAEIYLpSlLSUITLCBaGhNBQRM01M2mSCoXNUURIkZFxQvv';
        $output .= '/wz6724Wij2HCM7J6UyS/b+dmZ208rsww6jiqo4FhannZb5yDqjaNgDVwE/8JAmCMqF6fwGwbU0CKjD/+oAq9jcM27gxAFpNQxU3Bwi9A';
        $output .= 'jy8fgmGZuvaGAcIuwFA12CGce1jJESr6/Ot1i3Tnq5qptFqzet1jRA1F2XHWQFAs3RzwTTNhQd3rOkFU7c0DijmohRg1TR9ZmpCN7/8+P';
        $output .= 'X954fb+sTUjK7VLKOYi1IAaTQtUrfm8pP88/vTw8M5q06sZoOouSgHEDI5vrO/eHK28el04yxf3N8ZnyQooZiLfwA0arNb6d6bj998/+v';
        $output .= 'x8710a7bW4E2Uc1EKsEhz7WiQBK9eL29urrzsB8ngaK1JLDUXpYAkGSQH6e7640fL91dWXjxZ33138PZggA+Sz0WQlAL4gmewuzC1uCen';
        $output .= 'qXevMPWc9XrMX/VXh6Hicx4ByHEeAfRg/wtgSMAvz+CKEkYAnc5SpwuD4z70PM+hUf+4348ixF7EGItjxmQcCx/Dzv/SOkuXAF3PdT3GI';
        $output .= 'ujjGLELNYwxhF7M4oi//wsgdlYZdMXCmEUUSsSu0OOBACMoBTiu62BdRPEjYxozXFyIpK7IAE0IYa7jOBRqGlOK0BFq3Kdpup3DthFwP9';
        $output .= 'QDlBCGKEECoHEBEDLAXHAQMQnI8jwFYRQw3AMOQAJoOADoAVcDAh0HZAKQZUMZdC43kdeqAPwUBEsC+M4cIEq5KEEBCl90mR8CVR3nxwC';
        $output .= 'dBBS9OAe020UGnXb7KcxzPY9SXoEEIBZtgE7UDgBKyLMhgBS2YdzjMJb4XHRDAPiQhSGjNOxKQIZTgC8BiMECgarxprjjO0OXiV4MAf4A';
        $output .= '/x0nbcyiS5EAAAAASUVORK5CYII=';
        $output = base64_decode($output);
    }
    return $output;
}

$skin = get_skin($user);

$g = 4;
$p = ($size/100)*5;
$s = floor(($size-($p*2))/(48+($g*3)));
$p = floor(($size-($s*(48+($g*3))))/2);
$h = ($s*32)+($p*2);

$im = imagecreatefromstring($skin);
$mi = imagecreatetruecolor(64,32);
imagecopyresampled($mi,$im,0,0,64-1,0,64,32,-64,32);
$av = imagecreatetruecolor($size,$h);
imagesavealpha($av,true);
imagefill($av,0,0,imagecolorallocatealpha($av,0,0,0,127));

// Front
imagecopyresized($av,$im,$p+$s*4,$p,8,8,$s*8,$s*8,8,8);
imagecopyresized($av,$im,$p+$s*4,$p+$s*8,20,20,$s*8,$s*12,8,12);
imagecopyresized($av,$im,$p,$p+$s*8,44,20,$s*4,$s*12,4,12);
imagecopyresized($av,$mi,$p+$s*12,$p+$s*8,16,20,$s*4,$s*12,4,12);
imagecopyresized($av,$im,$p+$s*4,$p+$s*8+$s*12,4,20,$s*4,$s*12,4,12);
imagecopyresized($av,$mi,$p+$s*8,$p+$s*8+$s*12,56,20,$s*4,$s*12,4,12);

// Right
imagecopyresized($av,$im,$p+$s*$g+$s*16,$p,0,8,$s*8,$s*8,8,8);
imagecopyresized($av,$im,$p+$s*$g+$s*18,$p+$s*8,40,20,$s*4,$s*12,4,12);
imagecopyresized($av,$im,$p+$s*$g+$s*18,$p+$s*8+$s*12,0,20,$s*4,$s*12,4,12);

// Back
imagecopyresized($av,$im,$p+$s*$g*2+$s*28,$p,24,8,$s*8,$s*8,8,8);
imagecopyresized($av,$im,$p+$s*$g*2+$s*28,$p+$s*8,32,20,$s*8,$s*12,8,12);
imagecopyresized($av,$mi,$p+$s*$g*2+$s*24,$p+$s*8,8,20,$s*4,$s*12,4,12);
imagecopyresized($av,$im,$p+$s*$g*2+$s*36,$p+$s*8,52,20,$s*4,$s*12,4,12);
imagecopyresized($av,$mi,$p+$s*$g*2+$s*28,$p+$s*8+$s*12,48,20,$s*4,$s*12,4,12);
imagecopyresized($av,$im,$p+$s*$g*2+$s*32,$p+$s*8+$s*12,12,20,$s*4,$s*12,4,12);

// Left
imagecopyresized($av,$im,$p+$s*$g*3+$s*40,$p,16,8,$s*8,$s*8,8,8);
imagecopyresized($av,$mi,$p+$s*$g*3+$s*42,$p+$s*8,20,20,$s*4,$s*12,4,12);
imagecopyresized($av,$mi,$p+$s*$g*3+$s*42,$p+$s*8+$s*12,60,20,$s*4,$s*12,4,12);

// Black Hat Issue
imagecolortransparent($im,imagecolorat($im,63,0));

// Accessories
imagecopyresized($av,$im,$p+$s*4,$p,40,8,$s*8,$s*8,8,8);
imagecopyresized($av,$im,$p+$s*$g+$s*16,$p,32,8,$s*8,$s*8,8,8);
imagecopyresized($av,$im,$p+$s*$g*2+$s*28,$p,56,8,$s*8,$s*8,8,8);
imagecopyresized($av,$im,$p+$s*$g*3+$s*40,$p,48,8,$s*8,$s*8,8,8);

header('Content-type: image/png');
imagepng($av);
imagedestroy($im);
imagedestroy($mi);
imagedestroy($av);
```

The HTML for the textbox is like this:

```
<form action="skin.php" method="post">
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Username:"><br>
<div class="spacer"></div>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

How do I make so the "textbox' content, shows as:

> domain.com/skin.php?u={username}&s={size}

And how do I make a select box that choose which size it is? Please help!

All the codes I found, can be found here: https://github.com/jamiebicknell/Minecraft-Avatar

Comment: `<input type="text" name="u" /> <input type="text" name="s" />` but you'll either need to change the `form` to use `GET` or change the php to use `POST`

Comment: Your question seems to be off-topic because you can't show a minimal understanding of your code.